# Calculate differing accumulated storage charges over time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project for a wine importer, in which need to calculate the accumulated storage charges per SKU up to the delivery date.

I have data from the warehouse recording the `Date_In` and `Date_Out` so calculating `DATEDIFF('day', Date_In, Date_Out)` is fairly trivial. 
However every year the warehouse changes its prices, so when calculating the storage charges I need to split my `Days_in_Stock` across differing rates.

Input data with stock movement dates:

```
+----------------+------------+---------+-----+------------+------------+
| INVOICE_NUMBER | STOCK_CODE | CS_SIZE | QTY |  DATE_IN   |  DATE_OUT  |
+----------------+------------+---------+-----+------------+------------+
|           1001 | MP-BMB13   |       6 |   1 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-06-01 |
|           1002 | MP-BMB13   |       6 |   1 | 2019-03-01 | 2019-10-01 |
+----------------+------------+---------+-----+------------+------------+
```

Storage rates:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| DATE_EFFECTIVE | CASE_SIZE | COST_PER_WK |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+
| 2018-09-01     |         9 |      0.1375 |
| 2018-09-01     |         6 |     0.06875 |
| 2019-09-01     |         9 |      0.1425 |
| 2010-09-01     |         6 |     0.07125 |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
+----------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
| INVOICE_NUMBER | STOCK_CODE | DAYS_IN_STOCK | STORAGE_COST |
+----------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
|           1001 | MP-BMB13   |            92 |         0.90 |
|           1002 | MP-BMB13   |           214 |         2.10 |
+----------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

`DAYS_IN_STOCK` is calculated with `DATEDIFF('day', Date_In, Date_Out)`

`STORAGE_COST` is `COST_PER_WK * DAYS_IN_STOCK / 7`

The issue I have is where as with Invoice 1002 the `DAYS_IN_STOCK` spans more than one charge rate. In which case the calculation needs to be something like:

```
COST_PER_WK (before 2019-09-01)* DAYS_IN_STOCK (before 2019-09-01) / 7
+ 
COST_PER_WK (since 2019-09-01)* DAYS_IN_STOCK (since 2019-09-01) / 7
```

Ideally the final query would be able to handle cases where the item has been in stock for more than 2 charge rate periods too.

Approaches attempted so far:

- Hard coding the query to find number of days before and after the rate change, but I will eventually need to use data going back 5 years and implement the same thing for a much more complicated delivery rate table.
- Trying to JOIN `Date_In` to `Date_Effective`, but I couldn't get it to work, and have no idea how I would extend to 3 price rates.

I'm fairly stumped as to how to tackle this so any ideas would be very welcome. 
Currently using SQL Server 2017

Comment: So, with that data you have given us, what is the expected results? You say *"I've tried various approaches"* what were those attempts, and why didn't they work?

Comment: Thanks @Larnu I will update the original post now

Comment: Where have columns like `DATE_IN` and `STOCK_CODE` come from? Your sample data only has 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea on how to solve this.  I don't want to deal with weeks, so I'll phrase this answer in terms of days.

The basic idea is to add an end date to the rates table, then use `join` and aggregation:

```
with sr as (
      select r.*,
             lead(date_effective) over (partition by case_size) as date_end,
             cost_per_wk / 7.0 as cost_per_day
      from storage_rates r
     )
select i.*, sr.total_cost
from invoices i outer apply
     (select sum(datediff(day,
                          (case when i.date_in > sr.date_effective then i.date_in else sr.date_effective end),
                          (case when i.date_out < sr.date_eend then i.date_out else sr.date_end end)
                         ) * sr.cost_per_day
                 ) as total_cost
      from sr
      where i.cs_size = sr.cs_size and  -- I think the case size is relevant
            i.date_in < sr.date_end and
            i.date_out >= sr.date_effective
     ) sr;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've not seen or used `outer apply` before so that's something I've learnt today. Will try and implement now

Comment: @Frank . . . It is a lot like a correlated subquery in this example.

Comment: I have it working now. Initially it gave me an error of "Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference" and after a bit of searching I found that I could fix it by joining invoices again within the outer apply statement. Thanks again for your help!